# CUDA: 'name' has no value at the target location

Tags: cuda

in my code when i call findMax function, index variable can't defined but max,i can defined and work. i so try with different names but not works. what is problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CUDA compiler performs some optimizations even when you disable all optimizations. `index` has no side effect in the device function findMax so the compiler eliminated the variable.

Comment: What do you want to do?  index doesn't matter in your code.  If you modify your algorithm so index actually serves a purpose in the program, then the compiler won't be able to optimize it out.  Something like `if (index) return max; else return array[0];` might work.